# MySqli error on insert in PHP, but the same query string executes fine in terminal

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

I have some form data that need to be written into a database, after it's confirmed. I form a query string and pass it to mysqli, but get error that my primary key can't be null. It's not null, and query string is executed fine in mysql terminal.

```
$query_string = "insert into podnosilac (ime, prezime, jmbg) 
        values (
        aes_encrypt('". $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION["ime"])."', @key_str, @init_vector), 
        aes_encrypt('". $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION["prezime"])."', @key_str, @init_vector),
        aes_encrypt('". $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION["jmbg"])."', @key_str, @init_vector)
)";
if (!$mysqli->query($query_string)) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

This is the value of $query_string when I echo it just above mysqli->query line:

```
insert into podnosilac (ime, prezime, jmbg)
    values ( aes_encrypt('ivana', @key_str, @init_vector), aes_encrypt('corovic', @key_str, @init_vector), aes_encrypt('12345678910', @key_str, @init_vector) )
```

As a matter of fact, when I try this line:

```
$mysqli->query("insert into podnosilac (ime, prezime, jmbg)
    values ( aes_encrypt('ivana', @key_str, @init_vector), aes_encrypt('corovic', @key_str, @init_vector), aes_encrypt('12345678910', @key_str, @init_vector) )");
```

I still get "Column 'jmbg' cannot be null".

It's something to do with aes_encrypt. @key_str and @init_vector are defined on database, maybe this is not the way to pass them?

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Where are defined @key_str and @init_vector?

Comment: Does your primary key auto increment?

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: @EduardoGalván, key_str and init_vector are defined on database, from mysql terminal.

Comment: @ZachRattner, primary key does not increment. It's something like social security number

Comment: @Unex, this is the error I get: Column 'jmbg' cannot be null

Comment: well this means that `$_SESSION["jmbg"]` is null and it shouldn't.

Comment: But it's not, when I print it just above, it shows the correct vallue.

Comment: are you sure you are connecting to the correct database?

Comment: I have a hunch that the SQL variables `@key_str` and `@init_vector` are being set up in the SQL command line environment but not the PHP environment. What do you get if you `select @key_str, @init_vector` from PHP? (Just NULL or not NULL - you don't have to give anything away). Where and how are they set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think two things:

1) You are not connecting to the correct database

2) You are not setting these mysql variables when you create the connection to database. Do something like `$mysqli->query('SET @yourvariable := whatever');` right after your `mysqli_connect` because these variables are **session-specific**. This could explaing the query working on your terminal (where you actually setting these variables) and not working in your script (where you don't).

Comment: @Mike, key_str and init_vector were null. Those are user defined variables and they are available in mysql terminal for the session only. I have defined $key_str and $init_vector to use in php.